# PowerShell try catch finally

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I'm writing a powershell script right now to help speed up catching issues in an application that manages windows update.

I'm as far as pulling the machines being managed from the database, and I'm working on a block to handle different output. But I'm running into an issue with it throwing 2 messages for a single machine when I only want it to throw one and could use a hand

I realize it's still rough and needs some cleaning up, and I may just be low on caffeine, but here's the block I'm stuck on. or at least looking for ideas.

```
#Make sure the system is actually on before we try to access the registry and wait for timeout or error
if (Test-Connection $Device.IPAddresses -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
    Try { # test the registry connection, this will likely fail on workgroup systems
        if (Get-RemoteRegistryKey -RegKeyPath $RegKeyPath -RegValueName $RegValueName -ComputerName $Device.DNSname)
            {
            $SusClientID = $null # blank out the susclientid var so we don't unintentionally recycle it and put out bad data, because purple
            # now query the registry and put it into a var so we can fookin do stuff
            $SusClientID = Get-RemoteRegistryKey -RegKeyPath $RegKeyPath -RegValueName $RegValueName -ComputerName $Device.DNSname
            }
        else {Write-Output $Device.DNSname " is offline"}
        } # now catch errors, likely caused by credential issues or bad dns resolution
    Catch [UnauthorizedAccessException] {Write-Output ($Device.DNSname + " cannot access remote registry")
        }
    Finally { # finally lets compare the sysclient id on the machine to that in the database
        if ($SusClientID) # -match "\A[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}\z")
            {
            if ((Compare-Object $SusClientID $Device.SusClientId) -eq $null)
                {Write-Output ($Device.DNSname +" SusClientId matches database.")}
            elseif ($SusClientID -eq $null -or $SusClientID -eq "") {} # this didn't work as I'd hoped
            else {
                # notmatching a SusClientId GUID will not catch systems with malformed ID's, commenting this out until a better method is found
                #if ($SusClientID -notmatch "\A[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}\z")
                Write-Output ($Device.DNSname +" SusClientId does not match.")}
            }

        }
    }
```

Now the problem is, in my output below, i'm catching an exception for pc-001 and stating it can't be accessed, which is what I want, but then I'm also throwing a message that the susclientid doesn't match the one in the database because one wasn't collected that matches. the does not match message is working as desired for pc-005 though because I intentionally replaced it's susclientid in the registry

```
pc-001.sergeinc.org cannot access remote registry
pc-001.sergeinc.org SusClientId does not match.
pc-002.sergeinc.org SusClientId matches database.
pc-003.sergeinc.org SusClientId matches database.
srv-ad.sergeinc.org SusClientId matches database.
pc-xptest-001.sergeinc.org SusClientId matches database.
pc-004.sergeinc.org is offline
pc-005.sergeinc.org SusClientId does not match.
```

Comment: I think `$SusClientID = $null` should go before `Get-RemoteRegistryKey ...`.

Comment: You're right. That did it.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht make your comment into an answer to that the OP can accept

Answer (score 0):

This may be personal preference, but I'd try to put as few commands as necessary in any `try {...}` block. Nor am I sure whether it's worth having a `finally {...}` block. In this case I'd do something like this once you know that the device is on-line with the `Test-Connection` statement:

```
$SusClientID = $null
...

try {
  $SusClientID = Get-RemoteRegistryKey -RegKeyPath $RegKeyPath -RegValueName $RegValueName -ComputerName $Device.DNSname
}
catch {
  ...
}

if($SusClientID) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

This can make it clearer which statement is generating an error for the `catch {...}` block.

Note that if you're looping through a list of devices, it is definitely work setting **$SusClientID** to **$null** at the beginning of each loop, or alternatively setting it explicitly to **$null** if you catch an error.